# 'this' doesn't refer to the context from where it is called (for Arrow functions)

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Context of  **this**  doesn't work as expected. I have described my issue in as comments in the code below.

```
const dog = {

    //arrow function
    bark: () => {
        console.log(this);
    },

    makeBark(){
        // this here refers to the dog object
        // (as it is a normal function) 
        // so inside the bark function , shouldn't
        // this refer to the dog object ?  
        this.bark();
    },    

};        

dog.makeBark(); // this is the problematic function
```

I dont understand **WHY** `dog.makeBark()` prints window object . The parent scope of bark function is the dog object

Comment: Can you please add a description of what is your problem with the function and what do you expect?

Comment: The arrow function is never going to use anything other than the lexical `this`. It doesn't matter how you call it.

Comment: Remember that arrow functions are *lexically bound*. The lexical scope during an object initialisation is *not* the object.

Comment: @Quentin I don't think its a duplicate because the OP already knows the reason that why it is printing `window` object. He is confused in the third part

Answer (score 1):

The `this` of arrow function will be the `this` of its parent scope where its **declared** not where its **called.**

In the above example you are just calling `bark` from another function. This code doesn't change `this` of `bark`. Also `this` for an arrow function will remain same throughout the code and can never be changed implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: Isn't the parent scope the dog object ?

Comment: @TilakMaddy object can't be a scope.

Comment: How do you find scopes in general ?

Comment: @TilakMaddy I would say scope is something where you can write statements. Also notice in the above post by scope I mean function. I used the word `scope` because there is also global scope. But other than global scope in above post I mean `function`

Comment: so what is the parent function in which bark , the arrow function is declared ?

Comment: @TilakMaddy There is no parent function its parent scope. Which is global scope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195716/discussion-between-tilak-maddy-and-maheer-ali).